# validate email in zk by applying constraint

Tags: java, zk

I have applied following constraint for email

```
<textbox width="400px"
constraint="/^[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+@[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]{2,}\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,}(\.[A-Za-z0-9])?/: Please enter an e-mail address in proper format" >
```

In ZK, But this is showing error even if textbox is blank and u click on text box. But i want to validate only when user enters some value in textbox.

Can you please suggest, how can i modify this constraint for my requirement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The constraint seems right so far. You should use [Form Binding](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/MVVM/Data%20Binding/Form%20Binding) to have an intermediate model, which can hold even invalid data. Then the constraint is enforced before saving the intermediate data to your "real" model.

EDIT:

This matches **nothing** or an **email**.

`constraint="/^(?:([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+@[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]{2,}\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,}(\.[A-Za-z0-9])))?/: Please enter an e-mail address in proper format"`

Comment: In the given scenario i dont want to apply constraint if email text box is blank, but with above condition its showing error if box is blank, but i want to show error only when someone enters an invalid email.